# I have a white vertical line on my laptop screen

Tags: laptop, display, lenovo-laptop, laptop-display

I have a white vertical line on my laptop screen. It must be a hardware problem, as it appears, whatever the screen is showing.

This is a pic I made with my phone:

[image]

The laptop is a Lenovo G780. It even shows up on the BIOS!

Is there any remedy?

It always shows up:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's likely a hardware issue. No, probably no remedy you can do yourself, take it to a service shop.

Comment: Is it in exactly the same spot all the time (hard to judge from the pictures)?

Comment: Yes, it is always in the same place.Even in the BIOS

Comment: It's the screen. Nothing you can do except replace it. A decision not to be taken lightly as this are usually very expensive.